# Publishing ASP.NET MVC application to a web host - deploys files in the VS project structure instead of the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-deployment

I created a web application using ASP.NET MVC and want to publish to an online web hosting company that don't have any special extensions for VS etc.

I tried publishing by "FTP" but it has just copied all the files to the host, for example, the 'Views' folder with Index.cshtml has gone into (webhost)/Views/Index.cshtml and I still have the placeholder page supplied by my web host for the actual "root" of the domain (when I go to www.mysite.com)

What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing?

The application works perfectly well deployed locally and in debug mode..

Ugh!! I feel stupid for having to ask this but I think it's just a config issue and not something fundamental I've missed....hopefully!

Comment: Did you try `yourSite.com/Home/index?someRandomStringToAvoidCaching`

Comment: I hadn't, but I just tried /Home/index?xyz and get a "404.0" error... (from IIS)

Comment: Most probably its the appdomain not configured correctly. Check the site settings and see if framework version is not 2. It defaults to that.

Comment: Are u using asp.net 5?  Or earlier?

Comment: Deploying your application using FTP should work. which sitepath and destination URL are you using?

Comment: Sitepath: left blank (it gives the example of "e.g. wwwroot" but I didn't enter anything like that). Destination URL: http:// www.mysite.uk (I put a space in so it would display properly on SO but the actual URL doesn't have a space obviously).

Comment: Leave Destination URL empty. what are you using for the server?
Example: ftp.domainname.com  will deploy to the root. ftp.domainname.com/website will deploy to the folder website on your remote site

Comment: In IIS you need to check that your site is using a v4.0 application pool (integrated).  Sometimes the default app pool is v2.0 and this will block your site from loading properly

Comment: Tried with Sitepath and Destination URL blank. Same result... Server is ftp:// mysite.uk

Comment: whats your provider? godaddy?

Comment: Is it possible for me to check IIS app pool version using a web hosting interface (Plesk if it matters)?

Comment: My web provider? A UK company, Catalyst2.com

Comment: I'd say open up a ticket with your provider and have them confirm/configure your app pool.

Comment: Did you try change the webconfig file for system.web like this : 
`<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>`
The trick is trust level.

Comment: Did you delete any existing files on publish? Are you deploying 32-bit code this is disabled by default in modern IIS

Comment: MVC projects are deployed in this way, and this is not the issue. It sounds like it could be a routing problem. And, just to be sure, where is your view for the HomeController.Index action?

Comment: I had a similar problem when I first started deploying MVC projects.  It ended up being a server configuration issue.  Does you host service have an FAQ or other help?  In my case there was an IIS setting on the host that I had not configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that Your hosting provider supports ASP.Net.

You should try to publish Your site in Visual Studio using Web Deploy from generated publish settings file like so:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

, also remember to modify You web config file by setting `<compilation debug="true">` property to false.

usually You can download Your publish settings file from your hosting configuration control panel after making few settings